# How to have two different format of headings at the same “level” in a Table Of Content?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

I have the same style for headings at the Heading 1 level; they're identical except that in the table of content I would like to highlight one of them with grey background.
I tried to change 2 approaches:

1. Use different headings (e.g. Heading 1 and 2) with same style de facto, but I can't then in TOC place both of them on the same level, it doesn't work and it put heading 2 in level 2.
2. Use same Heading level like "Heading 1" and "Heading 1 highlighted" style which inherit from Heading 1. So doing I can place them at the same level BUT I can't format to be different in TOC.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 methods of doing this, but both not perfect.

**Method 1**

In this method TOC will lose the hyperlink functionality (you won't be able to click in TOC text, but page numbers will be hyperlinked) and the highlighted headers will be highlighted in TOC and in main text. Just use only one style e.g. H1 with outline level 1 and apply direct formatting to proper headers in the text. This will be reflected in TOC but only, when you remove "\h" switch from the TOC field.

**Method 2**

Similar to your #1. Use H1 style with outline level 1 and H2 with outline level 2. In the TOC they are displayed with TOC 1 and TOC 2 styles (or sth similar, I don't use English version). Edit TOC 2 style to be the same as TOC 1. The drawback of this method is that the headers are at different levels so the outline in navigation pane is incorrect.

Comment: I edited my TOC 2 with the same indentation of the paragraph as TOC 1 but with different background. Fortunately I do not need navigation pane so it's ok!